# Convert imported .less file into css string

Tags: reactjs, less, render-to-string

I have a .less file that is imported into a react component, is it possible to grab  that less file and write it into a string, preferably in the process of converting a react component to a html string?

Comment: Not sure this helps, but did you take a look at Webpack's [less loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/less-loader/)?

Comment: Why you need css string?